# How to find failed steps with `gh`

Tags: cicd, github-actions

I have a Github Actions workflow which contains several steps that allow continuation on error via `continue-on-error: true`. It is a scheduled workflow; the steps are independent of each other, and one step failing should not influence the others.

Unfortunately, in `gh run list` the whole run looks successful (green), even if a step failed. I am aware that `gh` supports `--json` and `--jq` to output data in JSON format, and apply `jq` filters, but I don't readily see a way to get a the information about individual steps.

Is there a way to find recent runs with failed steps using a `gh` command line?